# Guardar un documento generado por mi mediante clases de impresión

Tags: c#, visual-studio, impresión

Veréis, para poneros en situación, me enfrento a un problema al cual no encuentro solución por ningún lugar de intenet que me requiere imprimir, y a su vez guardar un ticket de compra cuyos datos me llegan desde un servidor y los cuales pinto yo desde la clase Graphics de PrintPageEventArgs.
No hay ningún problema en la impresión, todo se genera correctamente.

Lo que me gustaría saber es la forma de guardar el resultado de la impresión tras recorrer mi clase gráfica como un archivo .tif (podrían valerme formatos de imágen) tal y como se ve en un PrintPreviewDialog o en la propia impresión.
Puede ser que no sea lo más correcto enfocarlo desde este punto, pero lo más parecido que he conseguido a lo que quiero es lo que me muestra esta clase, he aquí un ejemplo de esto que me muestra:

[image]

Esto es mi parte del código que lanza la impresión, más abajo setteo los valores de cada cadena que pinto.
    var pd = new PrintDocument();

```
        pd.PrintPage += Pd_PrintPage;
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = szPrinterName;
        pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;

        pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = PATH + FileName;

        pd.Print();

        PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        ppd.ClientSize = new Size(400, 300);
        ppd.Document = pd;
        ppd.ShowDialog();
```

Aquí tengo el listener de la impresión que lanza el método de mi otra clase, que pinta todas las líneas:

```
private static void Pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        TicketsTemplateFactory.RedemptionTemplate(Ticket, e);
    }
```

En principio me gustaría intentarlo sin bibliotecas de terceros por temas de licencia.

Comment: Hola, tengo la idea pero no se si te entendi bien, lo que quieres hacer es guardar una copia del ticket que generas en un archivo en el disco?, corrigeme si me equivoco.

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, tienes el archivo como imágen, pdf o x formato, puedes utilizar la librería IO y utilizar la función File.ReadAllBytes de esta manera:

```
byte[] archivo = File.ReadAllBytes(RutaDelArchivo);
```

y pasas la variable archivo como parametro para la bd en un campo de valor varbinary(MAX). De esa manera lo guardas en la bd.

Espero te sirva! Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del evento `PrintPage` puedes guardar como imagen tu impresión haciendo uso del método `DrawImage` del objeto `Graphics` que recibe el manejador del evento en los parámetros, algo asi:

```
private static void Pd_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    TicketsTemplateFactory.RedemptionTemplate(Ticket, e);
    using (Image imagen = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("imagen.tif"))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imagen, new Point(0, 0));
    }
}
```